# Flash in iframe got 403 forbidden with NW.js

Tags: flash, proxy, http-headers, http-status-code-403, nw.js

I have an nw.js app in which I use an `iframe` tag to load an external page with a flash object. All traffic for the app is going through a TCP proxy I wrote. I didn't change any of the data, just doing some monitoring.

```
var gui = require('nw.gui')
// set proxy to my tcp proxy server
gui.App.setProxyConfig('localhost:5050')
```

The problem is, when making a request for the `.swf` file of the game, it returns a `403 Forbidden` error and the game does not load.

The proxy is functioning well, when I use it with Chrome, I can load the game page. And in the app, if I don't set the proxy, the game loads fine.

I compared the HTTP request for the `.swf` file with Chrome versus nw.js, they have some differences in the HTTP headers.

**In Chrome**

```
GET http://foo.bar/sth.swf HTTP/1.1
Host: foo.bar
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: ShockwaveFlash/17.0.0.134
Accept: */*
Referer: STH_VERY_LONG
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
```

**In nw.js**

```
GET http://foo.bar/sth.swf HTTP/1.1
Host: foo.bar
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Referer: STH_VERY_LONG
User-Agent: 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: zh-CN,en-us;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
```

**difference**

In nw.js it's missing the `Accept` and `X-Requested-With` headers, and the `User-Agent` header is empty. Other headers are all the same.

I tried add `nwUserAgent` attribute to `iframe` tag, as documented [here](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Mini-browser-in-iframe), but `User-Agent` header stays empty.

So I want to know:

- why the 2 headers are missing
- how can I get the app and proxy working together

THX.

**UPDATE**

The problem has been pinpointed to the `User-Agent` header. see [this issue](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/2850)